# In Python, is there a way to return a specific attribute value by accessing the class object directly, without specifying object.attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Test:

 def __init__(self):
    self.value = 1;

test = Test();
```

Is is possible to specify a way to access `value`by default when accessing the object itself? For instance:

```
a = 1 + test   # by default this would be equivalent to a = 1 + test.value
```

The reasoning for this question is that I have some standard objects with builtin validation and from which I will almost always only get the `value` attribute. The intention is just to reduce the clutter.

A user suggested overriding the specific necessary operation but before I could comment the answer was delited. That could work perhaps but I wonder if it is possible at a general level.

Comment: The problem with trying to provide a language feature like this is, how do you *prevent* the auto-conversion when you *don't* want it? Because the auto-conversion causes problems in a lot more cases than you seem to realize, and trying to infer whether you want the conversion from contextual clues is extremely error-prone.

Comment: If you almost always just want the `value` attribute, it'd make more sense to write a wrapper function that doesn't expose a `Test` instance to the caller at all and just returns the `value`. Callers can create a `Test` instance directly for the rare cases they need other functionality. (It may even make more sense to eliminate `Test` entirely, or have `Test` delegate to the function instead of the other way around.)

Comment: To give more details, I'm implementing these as settings types. Consider a class IntParameter which stores the value of the parameter, a minimum and maximum, a default and the name of the parameter. Using property decorators I automatically check if values are valid via the setter. 

During the system usage, after setting the value, I practically only call obj.value. At the end of the execution I may have to check if the value is different from the default. Perhaps it is not advisable to do what I asked, but I was curious nonetheless. Thanks for the discussion @user2357112supportsMonica!

Comment: @Chicoscience Inheriting `int` and then overwriting the `__new__` or `__init__` method might be a solution. This way you can also add your own methods or properties while using the instances just like an integer. The only problem with this that comes to my mind is that integers are unmutable in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the appropriate way, because by default, a Python class will return `None` if it's initialized. But if you still want to do it. You can use the `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

```
class Test:
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.value = 1
        return cls.value

test = Test()
print(test)
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: This doesn't actually create an instance of `Test` at all. It just sets a class attribute and returns `1`. You can't call any methods on the (nonexistent) instance, or do any of the stuff you need to do for the rare-but-existent cases where you don't just want the `value` attribute.

Comment: Agree. That's why I mentioned before it's not recommended to do this way.